# Trouble to connect via bluetooth with flutter_reactive_ble

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hello everyone!

I'm currently working with the package [flutter_reactive_ble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble)

But I'm struggling to make the connection consistent

Yesterday I figured that the problem would surely come from the :

```dart
if (connectionState.connectionState == DeviceConnectionState.connected)
```

Because most of the time it comes out as "connecting", but I'm not sure how to wait till it's connected if it comes out as "connecting" without checking in a loop like a sleep, the goal here is to go fast so the Ux is good

I'm working on a **Mac M1**  and testing on **Android**

**PS**: The code is not clean, but the goal is to make it work. ⚙️

Hope someone can help

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_reactive_ble/flutter_reactive_ble.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:qrcode/enum/characteristic_enum.dart';

class CadenaData extends StatefulWidget {
  CadenaData({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CadenaData> createState() => _CadenaDataState();
}

class _CadenaDataState extends State<CadenaData> {
  final flutterReactiveBle = FlutterReactiveBle();

  @protected
  @mustCallSuper


  void findCadena(BuildContext context) async {
    flutterReactiveBle.connectToDevice(
      id: "DC:30:FC:9F:45:91",
      connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
    ).listen(
      (connectionState) async {
        if (connectionState.connectionState ==   DeviceConnectionState.connected) {

    //doing stuff
         
        } else {
          print("connection failed\n $connectionState.connectionState");
        };
      },
      onError: (error) {
        print("error on connect $error");
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my problem with a "StreamSubscription" receiving the result of the "FlutterReactiveBle.connectToDevice()"

And a switch case to manage the different outputs of the stream.

```
late StreamSubscription<dynamic> _currentConnectionStream;

 _currentConnectionStream = flutterReactiveBle
    .connectToDevice(
  id: "DC:30:FC:9F:45:91",
  connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 15),
)
    .listen(
  (connectionState) async {

    switch (connectionState.connectionState) {
      case DeviceConnectionState.connecting:
        print("-- Connecting to device --");
        break;

      case DeviceConnectionState.connected:
        print(" -- Connected --");
        break;

      case DeviceConnectionState.disconnecting:
        print("-- disconnecting --");
        break;

      case DeviceConnectionState.disconnected:
        print("-- disconnected --");
        break;
    }
  },
  onError: (error) {
    print("error on connect $error \n");
  },
);
```